# Change the restrictions of a simpletype element in child type

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a type hierarchy in xsd like the following: Type A -> Type B -> Type C...

Now **Type B** is defined like:

```
   <xs:complexType name="TypeB">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TypeA" >
        <xs:sequence>
          ...
          <xs:element name="ElementA" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

**Type C** does not need to add any elements to Type B so it is defined like:

```
  <xs:complexType name="TypeC">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TypeB">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Now the restrictions for Type C for ElementA have changed - it's maxIncluse should be 5 not 10.

I can change Type C but changing Type B should not break compatibility.
Is there a way to change the restrictions without breaking compatibility/the existing hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by declaring TypeC as a restriction of TypeB and explicitly redefining its complex content. However, for it to work, you need to explicitly declare the simple type that restricts xs:int between 0 and 10, and explicitly restrict it to another simple type that changes the maxInclusive to 5. It is important that this simple type restriction is explicit, as explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#rcase-NameAndTypeOK).

The schema could look like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ElementC" type="TypeC"/>
  <xs:complexType name="TypeA">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foobar" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TypeB">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TypeA" >
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ElementA" type="Type10" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>  
  <xs:simpleType name="Type10">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="Type5">
    <xs:restriction base="Type10">
      <xs:maxInclusive value="5"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="TypeC">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="TypeB">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="foobar" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="ElementA" type="Type5" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and then this will be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ElementC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <foobar/>
  <ElementA>5</ElementA>
</ElementC>
```

and this not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ElementC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <foobar/>
  <ElementA>6</ElementA>
</ElementC>
```

Comment: Visual Studio tells me:
`Elements with the same name and in the same scope must have the same type.` when i use `<xs:element name="ElementA"...` in TypeC

Comment: That's strange. I successfully tried the schema with oXygen and it all went fine to validate the first document and reject the second one. What is the schema processor behind Visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry that was my fault!
Thank you for your Help!